# Reversing Linked List Confusion in Java

Tags: java, object, linked-list

I'm having difficulty understanding a particular line of code when reversing a linked list in Java. Here is the method:

```
public static ListNode reverseList(ListNode head)
{
    ListNode prev = null;

    while(head != null)
    {
        ListNode nextNode = head.next;
        head.next = prev;

        prev = head;
        head = nextNode;
    }

    return prev;
}
```

What I am having trouble with is the line `head.next = prev;`. When this happens, I assumed that nextNode's value would also change because it also points to head.next. However, it remained the same. I know this has something to do with object references but I am not exactly sure.

This confuses me because if I create 2 ListNode objects by pointing one to another likeso:

```
    ListNode test = new ListNode(5);

    ListNode test2 = test;
```

and modify the 'test' object's val and print it out from 'test2', I get the same exact value likeso:

```
    test.val = 8;

    System.out.println(test2.val); // this also prints out 8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some Pictorial images for better illustrations

Here head, node1 and nextNode is an object

[image]

As seen, headNext and nextNode is pointing to node1. `headNext` is not an object but just referencing to node1.

Next `headNext` is pointed to prev. Notice nextNode is still pointing to node1

[image]

For second example, after creating listNode `test` with value 5, test2 is assigned and pointed to test object. Hence any changes to test value will reflect to test2 too

[image]

Hope it helps to comprehend!

Comment: Thank you! The visualizations was much more clearer than the other explanation! I think I understand references and objects better now!